# Why increasing instances number doesn't increase Hive query speed

Tags: hive, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr, emr

I created a table using Hive in Amazon's Elastic MapReduce, imported data to it and partitioned it. Now I run a query that counts the most frequent words from one of table fields.

I run that query when I had 1 master and 2 core instances and it took 180 seconds to compute. Then I reconfigured it to have 1 master and 10 cores and it also takes 180 seconds. Why not faster?

I have almost the same output when running on 2 cores and 10 cores:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2

Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201208251929_0003, Tracking URL = http://ip-10-120-250-34.ec2.internal:9100/jobdetails.    jsp?jobid=job_201208251929_0003
Kill Command = /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.120.250.34:9001 -kill     job_201208251929_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 1
2012-08-25 19:38:47,399 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:00,482 Stage-1 map = 3%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:03,503 Stage-1 map = 5%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:06,523 Stage-1 map = 10%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:09,544 Stage-1 map = 18%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:12,563 Stage-1 map = 24%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:15,583 Stage-1 map = 35%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:18,610 Stage-1 map = 45%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:21,631 Stage-1 map = 53%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:24,652 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:27,672 Stage-1 map = 75%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:30,692 Stage-1 map = 89%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:39:33,715 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 23.11 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:34,723 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 23.11 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:35,730 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 23.11 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:36,802 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:37,810 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:38,819 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:39,827 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:40,835 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:41,845 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:42,856 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:43,865 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:44,873 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:45,882 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:46,891 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:47,900 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:48,908 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:49,916 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:50,924 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:51,934 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:52,942 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:53,950 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:54,958 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 72%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:55,967 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 72%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:56,976 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 72%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:57,990 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 90%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:39:59,001 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 90%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:00,011 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 90%, Cumulative CPU 62.57 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:01,022 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:02,031 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:03,041 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:04,051 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:05,060 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:06,070 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:07,079 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 72.86 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 minutes 12 seconds 860 msec
Ended Job = job_201208251929_0003
Counters:
Launching Job 2 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201208251929_0004, Tracking URL = http://ip-10-120-250-34.ec2.internal:9100/jobdetails.    jsp?jobid=job_201208251929_0004
Kill Command = /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.120.250.34:9001 -kill     job_201208251929_0004
Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2012-08-25 19:40:30,147 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-25 19:40:43,241 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:44,254 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:45,262 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:46,272 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:47,282 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:48,290 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:49,298 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:50,306 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:51,315 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:52,323 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:53,331 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:54,339 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:55,347 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:56,357 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:57,365 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 7.48 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:58,374 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
2012-08-25 19:40:59,384 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
2012-08-25 19:41:00,393 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
2012-08-25 19:41:01,407 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
2012-08-25 19:41:02,420 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
2012-08-25 19:41:03,431 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
2012-08-25 19:41:04,443 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 10.85 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 10 seconds 850 msec
Ended Job = job_201208251929_0004
Counters:
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Accumulative CPU: 72.86 sec   HDFS Read: 4920 HDFS Write: 8371374 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Accumulative CPU: 10.85 sec   HDFS Read: 8371850 HDFS Write: 456 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 minutes 23 seconds 710 msec
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only one reducer - and it is doing most of the work. I think it is a reason.

Comment: I tried once again and configured 1 **large** master instance and 2 **large** core instances and the job took 120 seconds so 60 seconds less than small instances.

Comment: You should compare not 120 vs s 180, but roughly (120-60) vs (180 vs 60) where 60 is job startup time. SO you got 2 times speedup

Comment: are you able to post the query? Certain things like "order by" in hive will always wind up going through a single reducer so they should be avoided if the result set is large.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should increase amount of reducers, on which you query executes.
It is done by the following code:

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=n;
```

where `n` is amount of reducers.

Then use `DISTRIBUTE BY` or `CLUSTER BY` clause (don't confuse with `CLUSTERED BY`) to distribute parts of the dataset as uniformly as possible between reducers. If you don't need sorting, better use `DISTRIBUTE BY` because

> `Cluster By` is a short-cut for both `Distribute By` and `Sort By`.

Here is the [link to hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy).